# Area of ​a parametrically defined function

Tags: parametric-functions, area

I can’t solve the problem; I need to find the area of ​​a parametrically defined function. According to the graph, part of the area has a negative sign.

```
\[Alpha] = 1.525;
\[Beta] = 3.95;
\[Chi] = 50;
Hr = 58.3;
He = 36.6;
Bmax = 1.5;
ParametricPlot[{\[Alpha] Sinh[Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Beta]] + 
   Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Chi], (Bmax^2 - (Bmax Sin[
         ArcTan[Hr/Sqrt[
          He^2 + ((\[Alpha] Sinh[Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Beta]] + 
              Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Chi]) )^2]]])^2)^(1/2)
     Sin[\[Gamma]] - (Bmax Sin[
       ArcTan[Hr/Sqrt[
        He^2 + ((\[Alpha] Sinh[Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Beta]] + 
            Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Chi]) )^2]]]) Cos[\[Gamma]]}, {\
\[Gamma], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Here is my solution, which I spotted on the forum:

```
With[{x = \[Alpha] Sinh[Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Beta]] + 
    Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Chi], 
  y = (Bmax^2 - (Bmax Sin[
          ArcTan[Hr/Sqrt[
           He^2 + ((\[Alpha] Sinh[Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Beta]] + 
               Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Chi]) )^2]]])^2)^(1/2)
      Sin[\[Gamma]] - (Bmax Sin[
        ArcTan[Hr/Sqrt[
         He^2 + ((\[Alpha] Sinh[Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Beta]] + 
             Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Chi]) )^2]]]) Cos[\[Gamma]]},
 NIntegrate[y D[x, \[Gamma]], {\[Gamma], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]]
```

but it does not take into account that part of the area is negative.
I will be glad for any help, thanks for your attention.

Comment: `Abs` or `With[{x = α Sinh[Bmax Sin[γ] β] + 
    Bmax Sin[γ] χ, 
  y = (Bmax^2 - (Bmax Sin[
            ArcTan[Hr/
              Sqrt[He^2 + ((α Sinh[
                    Bmax Sin[γ] β] + 
                    Bmax Sin[γ] χ))^2]]])^2)^(1/
        2) Sin[γ] - (Bmax Sin[
        ArcTan[Hr/
          Sqrt[He^2 + ((α Sinh[Bmax Sin[γ] β] + 
                Bmax Sin[γ] χ))^2]]]) Cos[γ]}, 
 1/2 NIntegrate[-y*D[x, γ] + 
    x*D[y, γ], {γ, -π, π}]]`

Comment: The sign of the area depends on the direction of the parametrized curve. To get a positive sign, you simple need to inverse the direction of the curve, by writing : `{\[Gamma], \[Pi], -\[Pi]}`

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Daniel Huber, Your solution is also very cool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to @cvgmt (see comment) here a vectorial solution `v[\[Gamma]]`using `Cross`

```
With[{v = {\[Alpha] Sinh[Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Beta]] + 
     Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Chi], (Bmax^2 - (Bmax Sin[
             ArcTan[Hr/
               Sqrt[He^2 + ((\[Alpha] Sinh[
                    Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Beta]] + 
                    Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Chi]))^2]]])^2)^(1/
         2) Sin[\[Gamma]] - (Bmax Sin[
         ArcTan[Hr/
           Sqrt[He^2 + ((\[Alpha] Sinh[Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Beta]] + 
                 Bmax Sin[\[Gamma]] \[Chi]))^2]]]) Cos[\[Gamma]]}}, 
 NIntegrate[Cross[v] . D[v, \[Gamma]]/2, {\[Gamma], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]]
 (* 558.924 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

α = 1.525;
β = 3.95;
χ = 50;
Hr = 58.3;
He = 36.6;
Bmax = 1.5;

{x, y} = {α Sinh[Bmax Sin[γ] β] + 
    Bmax Sin[γ] χ,
   (Bmax^2 - (Bmax Sin[
            
            ArcTan[Hr/
              Sqrt[He^2 + ((α Sinh[
                    Bmax Sin[γ] β] + 
                    Bmax Sin[γ] χ))^2]]
            ])^2)^(1/2) Sin[γ] -
    (Bmax Sin[
        ArcTan[
         Hr/Sqrt[He^2 + ((α Sinh[Bmax Sin[γ] β] + 
                Bmax Sin[γ] χ))^2]]
        ]) Cos[γ]};

plt = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {γ, -π, π},
   PlotStyle -> Red,
   AspectRatio -> 1/2];

poly = Polygon[Cases[plt, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity]];

Show[plt, Region[Style[poly, Opacity[0.5, LightBlue]]]]
```

[image]

```
Area[poly]

(* 559.066 *)
```

Comment: "@Bob Hanlon Thank you, I will study Poly and Cases